# MongoDB Removing Duplicate subdocuments

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is the design of my schema. (1 document shown, thousands total in db).  Everything is in the same collection.

Document 1:

```
{
    pageNumber: 0,
    results: [
        {
            jobkey: "AAA", 


        },
           {
            jobkey: "BBB",


        },
           {
            jobkey: "CCC",


        }
    ]
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
    pageNumber: 0,
    results: [
        {
            jobkey: "RRR", 


        },
           {
            jobkey: "VVV",


        },
           {               //This Entire Object needs to be removed
            jobkey: "AAA", //Duplicate jobkey value of document 1
                           //remaining objects in array should stay

        }
    ]
}
```

Each document has a results key that takes in an array of objects.  Each one of these objects has a jobkey and corresponding value. Within a given results array, no two jobkeys have the same value.

**The issue:**

Whenever a jobkey value shows up more than once in the database, I need to remove one of the duplicate objects.  It is possible for the same jobkey value to be present in multiple results arrays.

I have been unable to find a way to get this done in the mongo shell or through mongoose.

Comment: The jobkey's can't be duplicates _within_ a document, or duplicates in different documents? Can there be the same jobkey in a different document?

Comment: Also, you need to remove the duplicates from existing documents, or just future ones?

Comment: I only need to remove duplicates from the existing database.  I won't be adding any additional records in the future.

The above code sample shows one document.  There aren't any duplicates in that document.  But the next document may have a results key that contains jobkeys with duplicate values to the ones listed above.  Let me know if that makes sense? I'll work on pasting an exact example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an odd definition of "duplicate" to me since the values are actually in separate documents. Subsequently you would have no real way of enforcing this in future operations without essentially querying the entire collection to see if that value was present in any document before you added it to your target document.

In order to detect and remove the "duplicates" you would have to resort to an operation like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match only where array has content
    { "$match": { "results.0": "$exists } },

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$results" },

    // Group the keys with counts keep the doc _id's
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$results.jobkey",
        "_ids": { "$push": "$_id" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    // Filter only duplicate matches
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc._ids.shift();    // remove the first element
    db.collection.update(
        { "_id": { "$in": doc._ids } },
        { "$pull": { "results": { "jobkey": doc._id } } },
        { "multi": true }
    )
})
```

Essentially determining a list of the terms you deem to be a "duplicate" then iterating that list to remove the documents within the array of the other documents that are considered to contain a "duplicate" of one existing inside another document.

This is also taking an arbitrary judgement that the "first" document in which the "duplicated" value is found is the place where it needs to stay. You could add a [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) before [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) if the place where you want to keep it matches some other set of rules.

The list is kept because only the documents that are not that "first" document are the ones you want to update. Of course the later [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) filters out any results where there was only one occurrence of the same value within the grouped key.

In iterating those results you just "remove" that "first" document `_id` from the list since that is the one you keep. The subsequent `.update()` operation matches only the "duplicate" documents in the list. The "update" portion of the statement uses [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to remove the array elements that match the specified value to the jobkey in all documents that were matched by the query.

If your ongoing intention is to keep those sub-document elements with "unique" jobkey values, then your use case is probably better suited to storing those documents inside another collection and keeping only references to those documents inside the array of the parent. In a separate collection you can then use a "unique constraint" on the index that would stop duplicate values from being inserted.

Comment: Great post.  I agree it's not an ideal format for the database.  The issue is that I'm pulling data from the indeed.com api for a school project and the max number of results I can get per page is 25.  So each time I do a pull I end up creating a new document.

Ideally I would like to have a database only containing information found within the results array, and remove the parent document all together.  The only issue is that there is one key/value pair in the parent document that I need to keep.